# How to pass a value of variable to a function in PHP (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, variables

Ok, so I have this code:

```
//let's say: 
$period = 30;
if (!function_exists('filter_where')) {
    function filter_where($period,$where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$period days")) . "'";
    return $where;
    }
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

This code is not working, because in the filter_where function, the value of $period is not 30.
How to pass the value of $period(which is 30) so I can use it in strtotime("-$period days") ?
The value of $period can be filled by user, so it might change to other number than 30.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the global keyword to import variables from the global namespace. More reading here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

```
//let's say: 
$period = 30;
if (!function_exists('filter_where')) {
    function filter_where($where = '') {
    global $period;
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$period days")) . "'";
    return $where;
    }
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
```

EDIT: I removed the $period variable from your function's declaration

Comment: no, it doesn't work. The $period inside the function returns null, instead of 30.

Comment: Check again, I removed the $period from your function's parameter list. It shouldn't be there.

Comment: it still returns null, instead of 30.
I put echo ("period2=$period"); after global $period; declaration to check the value and it returns null.

Comment: Then there is something else you are doing wrong. Try with a new php file just this code (of course call the function manually)

Comment: Ahh...
I found the problem!
This filter_where function is located inside another function. So I have to make another additional global $period declaration on the parent function.
Thanks a lot! It works now!